# Stacking columns and merging rows on Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-studio

Im working in Bootstrap Studio and tying to understand Bootstrap (v4.x) and flexbox. Flexbox doesnt make things easier. As many persons have tried, and asked here on Stack, im also trying to get columns to behave properly... So far no luck.

**Desktop view**
Logo | Search bar | icons

**Mobile view** (sm and lower)
Logo | icons
Search (100%)

I've tried possibly everything except the right thing... Ive played with flexbox 'order'/ push/pull, etc...

Maybe im approaching this from the wrong side... 'They' say that bootstrap is 'mobile-first'. So the code must be written as "Logo | icons | Search" or the desktop way?

```html
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" id="logo">Logo</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" id="search">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group"><input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Zoeken..." /></div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 justify-content-lg-end justify-content-xl-end">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <div role="group" class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-lg" role="button" href="#">Icon</a><a class="btn btn-lg" role="button" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown btn-group" role="group"><a class="btn btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="button">icon</i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">test</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log uit...</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a question, check Bootstrap documentation first. It contains lost of information, which might contain the fix you're looking for: [Order class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#reordering)

Before going into the fix, I want to point out that Mobile First approach is that you focus and build the views on mobile devices, and then you override those styles to make sure it will work on desktop or larger screens as well. That way you make sure your app looks nice even in narrow screens.

If you do Mobile First, the layout should look like:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            Logo
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div role="group" class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-lg" role="button" href="#">Icon</a>
                <a class="btn btn-lg" role="button" href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle" 
                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Dropdown
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">test</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log uit...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" 
                        placeholder="Zoeken..." />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After you get that done for mobile views, then you focus on the desktop views. The only thing I need is to change the column widths and set their orderings:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 order-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 order-md-1">...</div>
</div>
```

That's already working like what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ndsk4hL3/13/

But my OCD is telling me you can do better. I don't know if you read the Bootstrap documentation and realize there is a component called [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/) you can use?

[image]

I don't want to do everything for you so I purposely left navbar demo as it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ndsk4hL3/25/

Comment: Amazing! Ive read and read and read the Bootstrap docs. It takes a different viewing point (mobile first) so the code also has to mimic that!

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hourse fiddling :-) I got it working! It is a slight tweak from the answer by David (which is already amazing)

Basically first you build the blocks for Mobile:
Block A | Block B | Block C

Block C is always expanded (12) on XS and SM
Block A/B are always size 6 on XS/SM
And at MD the size becomes : 3-6-3

And last but not least, on MD and larger Block 3 is "ordered" to be displayed before Block 2!!

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-6 col-md-3">.col-6 .col-md-3</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 order-md-3">.col-6 .col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-2">.col-12 .col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

I used a slight tweak of the code by David. His solution will 'break' at SM (he used col-sm-6) instead of col-6 (which applies to XS)...